# Multiple OR condition in SQL query

Tags: sql, fine-tuning

The below query is taking way longer to execute as the table has more than 50M record and It seems the OR condition is not right in the query.... Can anyone please provide the optimized version for my query . Appreciate..!!

```
    DECLARE @LastRunDate DATETIME
SELECT @LastRunDate=LastRunDateTime FROM [DataAudit].[t_DeltaSetting] da 
WHERE da.[InterfaceName] = 'ATKInnovationTargetedCustomersToHANA'


SELECT distinct (initi.RecordID )
from WebData.t_Initiative initi
              inner join WebData.t_InitiativeCustomer ic on initi.RecordID=ic.InitiativeId
              inner join WebData.t_Tracker track on track.InitiativeId = initi.RecordID
              inner join WebData.t_TrackerCustomer tc on tc.TrackerId=track.RecordID

              where (initi.UpdatedDate >  @LastRunDate) 
              or (ic.UpdatedDate > @LastRunDate) 
              or (track.UpdatedDate > @LastRunDate) 
              or (tc.UpdatedDate > @LastRunDate)
```

Comment: Look at your indexes.  Or if you can provide execution plan and upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `union`:

```
SELECT initi.RecordID
FROM WebData.t_Initiative initi
WHERE initi.UpdatedDate > @LastRunDate
UNION
SELECT ic.InitiativeId
FROM WebData.t_InitiativeCustomer ic
WHERE ic.UpdatedDate > @LastRunDate
UNION
SELECT track.InitiativeId
FROM WebData.t_Tracker track
WHERE track.UpdatedDate > @LastRunDate
UNION
SELECT tc.TrackerId
FROM WebData.t_TrackerCustomer tc 
WHERE tc.UpdatedDate > @LastRunDate;
```

This assumes that `InitiativeID` is always a valid `RecordID`.  If not, you need additional logic for that validation (using `JOIN`, `IN`, or `EXISTS`).